# Handling possible type of import errors

Tags: python

I am trying to handle possible errors seen during import operations at the beginning of the execution of python program.

```
try:
    import sys
    import re
    import foobar
except ImportError as impErr:
    print("[Error]: Failed to import {}.".format(impErr.args[0]))
    sys.exit(1)
```

This code is working fine. However I am not confident that this is enough to catch the possible issues during import. For example , will this catch `ModuleNotFoundError` exception ?

> exception ModuleNotFoundError A subclass of ImportError which is
>   raised by import when a module could not be located. It is also raised
>   when None is found in sys.modules.
>
> New in version 3.6.

If just using `ImportError` is not enough, can someone please tell how to use OR condition to catch exception from `ImportError` and `ModuleNotFoundError`?

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError` is a subclass of `ImportError` - so your `except` block will catch both

Comment: rdas answered your question. All import errors will be caught by that `except` block, what could pass that is if you have some side effect in module level that raises an error, but this is not an *import* error, is another kind of error, and modules with side effects are evil and should not exist :p

Comment: On your second question, see [the official Python tutorial on Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Comment: Just to illustrate if your foobar module has this code `1/0` then, that except will not save you, but again this is *NOT* an *import* error, is a arbitrary error, it can be anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try:
    import sys
    import re
    import foobar
except (ImportError, ModuleNotFoundError) as (impErr, mNFE):
    print("[Error]: Failed to import {}." etc...
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: I think you could also replace impErr and mNFE with just one "provokedError" for example to shorten code.

Comment: I didn't know that tuple syntax, cool. What happens to mNFE variable if an the exception is an `ImportError` (but not a ModuleNotFoundError). It goes to None?

Comment: I've never honestly assigned the error to a variable. I just check if there's an error and then just point it out or do a specific action. But I guess it should go None. Also I should point out that MDNE is a succession of ImportError, so in most cases you won't need extra exceptions if it is just for debugging purposes.

Comment: And about the None thing, I think you may be able to write it as "except (ImportError as impErr, ModuleNotFoundError as mNFE)".

Answer (score 4):

It is enough to use just `ImportError` because `ModuleNotFoundError` is a sub-class of `ImportError`, but if you want to do some extra stuff on `ModuleNotFoundError` you may want to use below code.

```py
try:
    import sys
    import re
    import foobar
except ModuleNotFoundError as moduleErr:
    print("[Error]: Failed to import (Module Not Found) {}.".format(moduleErr.args[0]))
    sys.exit(1)
except ImportError as impErr:
    print("[Error]: Failed to import (Import Error) {}.".format(impErr.args[0]))
    sys.exit(1)
```